# Having problem understanding CGPathAddArc

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, uiviewanimation

In an iPad application, I want to move a layer anti-clockwise along an arc which has a center point of (768, 512) and radius of 512. I want it to start at 12 o'clock (which is top right corner of the screen) and finish at 6 o'clock (bottom right corner).

After a lot of try-and-fail, I got the code working

```
CGPoint origin = logo.layer.position;

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);
CGPathAddArc(curvedPath, NULL, 768, 512, 512, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, YES);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
pathAnimation.duration = 2;
[logo.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curve"];
```

But the problem is I can't understand the starting angle and end angle parameter. Why should I use -M_PI_2 and M_PI_2 respectively and set the clockwise to YES?

I think I am moving the object from 90 degree to 270 degree anti-clockwise, thus the code should be
`CGPathAddArc(curvedPath, NULL, 768, 512, 512, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, YES);`

I am probably wrong in multiple places and by chance got the correct result.

Please correct me and help me understand the two angle parameters:

startAngle

```
The angle (in radians) from the horizontal that determines the starting point of the arc.
```

endAngle

```
The angle (in radians) from the horizontal that determines the ending point of the arc.
```

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The location of 0 is on the X axis, like this:

```
    3*PI/2
      |
PI ---|--- 0
      |
     PI/2
```

-PI/2 is equivalent to 3PI/2.

You're effectively starting your rotation at the same place (-PI/2, 3*PI/2, 5*PI/2, etc., are all equal)

"12 o'clock" as you're thinking of it is 3*PI/2 or -PI/2... and you're rotating down to "6 o'clock" which is PI/2

Comment: the upside down y axis confuses me.. also, thanks, it helped me :)